# How to implement IDisposable pattern for a serial connection wrapper

Tags: c#, wrapper, idisposable

I am designing a C# library that uses FTDI library to manage FTDI devices and their connections. I model it in three levels of operations:
1. Enumerate plugged devices;
2. Open/Close a connection to a specific device;
3. Write to the device, and receive bytes from it.

Currently I have the following classes:

```
public static class FtdiEnumerator
{
    public static IEnumerable<FtdiDevice> Enumerate()
    {
        FTDI ftdi = new FTDI();
        FTDI.FT_STATUS status;
        uint bufferLenght = 0;
        status = ftdi.GetNumberOfDevices(ref bufferLenght);
        FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[] result = new FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[bufferLenght];

        if (status != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            return Enumerable.Empty<FtdiDevice>();

        status = ftdi.GetDeviceList(result);
        if (status != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            return Enumerable.Empty<DispositivoFtdi>();

        return result.Where(node => node != null)
                     .Select(node => new DispositivoFtdi(node))
                     .ToArray(); ;
    }
}


public class FtdiDevice
{
    protected FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE _node;
    protected FTDI _ftdi = new FTDI();

    public string Description => _node.Description;
    public string SerialNumber => _node.SerialNumber;

    public FtdiDevice(FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE node)
    {
        _node = node;
    }

    public void Open(uint baudRate = 115200)
    {
        FT_STATUS status = _ftdi.OpenBySerialNumber(_node.SerialNumber);

        if (status != FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            throw new Exception();

        status = _ftdi.SetBaudRate(baudRate);

        if (status != FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            throw new Exception()
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        _ftdi.Close();
    }


    public void Write(byte[] bytes)
    {
        uint bytesReceived = 0;
        _ftdi.Write(bytes, bytes.Length, ref bytesReceived);
    }
}
```

I know about the IDisposable pattern, and I see a clear use case for it here, regarding `FtdiDevice.Open()` and `FtdiDevice.Close()` methods, but I see that usually the pattern is implemented with *another*, additional class. I imagine something like a `FtdiConnection` class, to be used like this, I think:

```
var device = new FtdiDevice(node);
using (FtdiConnection connection = device.Open())
{
    connection.Write(bytes);
}
```

That would imply moving the `Write(byte[] bytes)` method to this `FtdiConnection` class.

I am not sure if I am in the right track, or how much sense my idea makes, and would appreciate any clarification.

Comment: Having separate `FtdiConnection` implies that there might be multiple such connections to the same device at the same time, which I doubt is the case here. So you can just implement `IDisposable` on device class itself.

Comment: It can be indeed with the connection, my opinion is that design is beter, but also with your approach right now FtdiDevice can be IDisposable and then caller could take care to dispose it...@Evk if connection itself is used within device than you don't have problem. It is always possible also to create two objects with the same node, then you have the same problem which you mentioned...

Comment: Thanks guys. If I implement IDisposable in the `FtdiDevice` class itself, then `Open()` would not return anything, is that right? How do I write the `using` expression so that `Close()` is called at the end?

Comment: @heltonbiker check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715247/what-is-the-resulting-behavior-when-an-idisposable-is-passed-into-a-parent-idisp/44715560#44715560 , maybe it can help you in further implementation.

Comment: The close should be called into the method dispose. If you are going to implement in the FtdiDevice class, it may be interesting to call the open method in the constructor, optionally with a speed. That way you do not need to call the open in to the using scope

Comment: You need to take a closer look at this "ftdi library", use a decompiler if necessary.  If it is done correctly, little reason to assume it is not, then it already implements a finalizer and Dispose() for its FTDI class.  Then all you do is call its Open() method in your constructor and implement your Dispose() by calling the library's dispose.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah, I thought so some time ago. Actually the FTDI class does not implement, and also does not have methods that return, IDisposable. Every method return `FT_STATUS`, which is an `enum`. Thanks for the suggestion, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do this:

```
public class FtdiConnection : IDisposable
{
   private FtdiDevice device;
   public FtdiConnection(FtdiDevice device)
   {
       this.device = device;
   }
   public void Dispose()
   {
       device.Close();
   }
}
```

into your open method:

```
public FtdiConnection Open(uint baudRate = 115200)
{
    ... Open ...
    return new FtdiConnection(this);
}
```

and use like

```
var device = new FtdiDevice(node);
using (FtdiConnection connection = device.Open())
{
    connection.Write(bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out, inspired on the discussion and previous answer, the following design answers my needs. I will add it here as an alternative to Gustavo's answer, and would be glad to know other alternatives.

The solution principle here is to have `Device.Open()` to return `this` as the disposable, thus avoiding the need for an additional `Connection` class:

```
using System;

namespace DisposableConnection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var device = new Device();

            using (device.Open())
            {
                device.Write();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Device : IDisposable
    {
        public Device()
        {
        }

        public IDisposable Open()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Open!!");
            return this;
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Close!!");
        }

        internal void Write()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write!!");
            //throw new Exception();   // optional, also works
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```